# Operations such as slicing will also slice the index?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series

I have read the below sentences in the documentation of pandas:

> "Series acts very similarly to a ndarray, and is a valid argument to
> most NumPy functions. However, operations such as slicing will also
> slice the index."

I'm not sure what the second sentence is saying. Isn't it a given that it would slice into the index?

Comment: A `pandas.Series` is like a 1d array, but it also has a `index`, or 'axis labels'.  A `ndarray` does not have a separate 'index' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

series = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
array = series.to_numpy()

# Outputs 4, because that is element 2 of [2,3,4].
print(array[2:5][2]) 

# Outputs 2, because series[2:5] now has index [2,3,4], so the
# element with index 2 is still 2.
print(series[2:5][2])
```

Since slicing a Series, unless you are using `.iloc`, uses the series' index, while ndarray doesn't have an index, a Series and ndarray will not always behave similarly.

This also means that code intended to have an ndarray input can fail in unexpected ways, or have unintended results, when a Series is used as input instead, unless the code ensures it is working with an ndarray.